# How to ensure the move constructor is used

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor, move-assignment-operator

The code below gives the error:

```
use of deleted function ‘constexpr B::B(const B&)’
```

now, I know this happens because the copy constructor is (intentionally) implicitly deleted by specifying a move constructor, and that copying the vector causes the calls to the (deleted) copy constructor. I think I also understand why the vector's copy constructor and assignment operator are used. I clearly want to use the move constructor and assignment operator though: move the object, so also move the vector it contains. So, **how do I get my move constructor/assignment operator to use the vector's move constructor/assignment operator?**

Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>

class B {
private:
    /* something I don't want to copy */
public:
    B() {};
    B(B&& orig) {/* move contents */};
    B& operator=(B&& rhs) {
        /* move contents */
        return *this;
    };
};

class A {
private:
    vector<B> vec;
public:
    A() : vec() {};
    A(A&& orig) : vec(orig.vec) {};
    A& operator=(A&& rhs) {
        vec = rhs.vec;
        return *this;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ensure that the "move" constructor and assignment operators are called, you **need to provide an object of the correct value category**. The value category is used to determine which operators and constructors could be used.

Use [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) to change the [value category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) (from the lvalue in this case) to a xvalue (an rvalue, that can be moved from).

```
// ...
A(A&& orig) : vec(std::move(orig.vec)) {};
A& operator=(A&& rhs) {
    vec = std::move(rhs.vec);
    return *this;
};
```

The `move` does not copy or change the object in any way, it is simply a cast to an rvalue reference of the argument type - hence modifying the value category.

Answer (score 9):

Just call `std::move` on the vectors in the expression in which you want to move from them:

```
class A {
private:
    vector<B> vec;
public:
    A() : vec() {};
    A(A&& orig) : vec(std::move(orig.vec)) {};
    //                ^^^^^^^^^
    A& operator=(A&& rhs) {
        vec = std::move(rhs.vec);
        //    ^^^^^^^^^
        return *this;
    };
};
```

Even though you take in rvalue references, `rhs` and `orig` are still lvalues in the function, so you need to call `std::move` on them.

Answer (score 2):

If all the members of your class are the objects of classes with correctly defined move constructor/assignment operator you should better use [default](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Special_member_functions) move constructor/assignment operator for your class. This would be much easier and less error-prone and ensure the call of move constructor/assignment operator of class members.

In your particular example it would be:

```
class A
{
private:
    vector<B> vec;
public:
    A() : vec() {};
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;
};
```

Comment: I find it hard to find in the specs, but I assume that the default move constructor calls the move constructors for all base classes and members? If so, this might be the correct solution in this case.

Comment: @Oebele watch section 12.8 paragraph 15 of [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf)